# Is there a way to import variables directly into routing module from files in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an angular project and I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a variable from a file directly into routing module?
I know we can do

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':variable/home/:variable,
        component: HomeComponent
     },
]
```

The issue is, I have the following

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: ':variable',
    children: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/about/',
            component: AboutComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'new',
            component: NewComponent
        },
        ]
    }
]
```

I need the parent "variable" apply to each route and I have no idea where to import it from. I have a globals.ts file and I thought it would be logical to import it from there, but since I'm not declaring a component I can't do it. Is there a way to do

```
let variable = "test"

{path: variable,
```

instead of

```
{path: ':variable',
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try defining a route path like

```
 export class AppRoutes {
    public static home: string = "home";
}
```

then import it into your routing module then
do something like

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {
  path: AppRoutes.home, component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

**As per getting the variable set from a file.**
You could try creating a service that reads from a file and then you can dynamically set the routes to the App route class that i described first.
you could create variables like home, about , etc and there values in the service would be set from whatever the values in the file are.
Example

```
 export class AppRoutes {
        public static home: string = this.fileService.home;
    }
```